# Able to retrieve records in tasklet through crud repository ,but unable to save or update a table (using .save/.saveAll) in an Azure sql table

Tags: spring, spring-data, azure-sql-database, spring-batch

I have created a tasklet using spring batch. In the execute method I am trying to retrieve records from azure sql db and I am successfully able fetch records in a list .But when I try to update any row in the same table using .save /.saveAll ,the table does'nt get updated nd no error is thrown.

```
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) 
throws Exception {

    List<PayoutBatch> payoutBatchRecords = 
    payoutBatchRepository.findByPayoutDate("08101994");
    RECORD_COUNT = payoutBatchRecords.size();

    recordsPerSlave = recordsPerSlave(RECORD_COUNT);

    setBatchID(payoutBatchRecords, recordsPerSlave);
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}


@Transactional
private void setBatchID(List<PayoutBatch> payoutBatchRecords(this is list with table 
records, int recordsPerSlave(here 10)) throws 
Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < payoutBatchRecords.size(); i++) {
        if (i % recordsPerSlave == 0) {
            BatchidAutoInc++;
        }
        batchId = payoutBatchRecords.get(i).getPayoutDate() + "_" + BatchidAutoInc;
        payoutBatchRecords.get(i).setBatchId(batchId);
    }
    try {
        payoutBatchRepository.saveAll(payoutBatchRecords);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.info("Exception encountered while saving data : {} "+e.getMessage());
        throw new PayoutMasterBatchJobException("Error while inserting/updating data ",e);
    }

}
```

This is my model class ::

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "payoutbatchtable")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class PayoutBatch implements Persistable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "memuuid")
    private String memUUID;

    @Column(name = "payout_date")
    private String payoutDate;

    @Column(name = "payoutid")
    private String payoutID;

    @Column(name = "jobstatus")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "batch_id")
    private String batchId;

    public PayoutBatch(String memUUID, String payoutDate, String payoutID, String status) {
        this.memUUID = memUUID;
        this.payoutDate = payoutDate;
        this.payoutID = payoutID;
        this.status = status;
        this.batchId = null;
    }

    public PayoutBatch() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getId() {
        return memUUID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return getId() == null;
    }
}
```

Note :: Am I missing some annotation or there is any issue with the code I am writing.

Answer (score 0):

The tasklet will be executed in a transaction driven by Spring Batch, so there is no need to add `@Transactional` on `setBatchID` method. Here is an excerpt from the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#taskletStep):

```
Each call to a Tasklet is wrapped in a transaction.
```

You need to remove `@Transactional` and make sure the transaction manager you want to use is correctly set on the step.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the quick response. Even if I remove @Transactional ,the db doesn't update . Also while running the job ,I see "No transaction manager was provided, using a DataSourceTransactionManager". I do not know if this is fine. And how to configure Transaction Manager explicitly .
This is how I am trying to configure my Transaction Manager,but still it does not work

Comment: @Bean("bajMasterpayout")
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository,Step getStep,JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) throws PayoutMasterBatchJobException {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener)
                .repository(jobRepository)
                .start(getStep)
                .build();

    }

Comment: @Bean
    public Step getStep(PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) throws PayoutMasterBatchJobException {

        return this.stepBuilderFactory
                .get("getStep")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .tasklet(payoutDbReadTasklet).build();
    }

Comment: If you use JPA, you need to configure SB to use a `JpaTransactionManager` and not a `DataSourceTransactionManager`.